# Adding fit line to multiple ggplot outputs

Tags: r, ggplot2, graphics, glm

I'm utilizing the following code to plot each regressor in `X_train` against the response variable `won` using a logistic model from `glm()`

```
require(reshape2)
require(ggplot2)
regressors = melt(X_train[2:16], id.vars='won')
ggplot(regressors) +
  geom_jitter(aes(value,won, colour=variable),) + 
  geom_smooth(aes(value,won, colour=variable), method="glm", method.args = list(family = "binomial")) +
  facet_wrap(~variable, scales="free_x")
```

[image: Output]

I thought the `geom_smooth()` command would add the fitted logistic regression line to each plot, but I can't seem to get it to work. I also tried passing "`data=X_train`" to the command as well. Any advice is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Please provide `dput` of `regressors`, or at least a subset sufficient to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your TRUE/FALSE needs to be converted to 1/0.

Here's an example with `mtcars` data:

```
library(dplyr); library(ggplot2)

# doesn't work
regressors <- pivot_longer(mtcars, -mpg)

# still doesn't work
regressors <- pivot_longer(mtcars, -mpg) %>% 
                mutate(mpg = (mpg > median(mpg)))
# Warning messages:
# 1: Computation failed in `stat_smooth()`:
# y values must be 0 <= y <= 1 
# ...


# works
regressors <- pivot_longer(mtcars, -mpg) %>% 
                mutate(mpg = (mpg > median(mpg)) %>% as.numeric())

ggplot(regressors) +
  geom_jitter(aes(value,mpg, colour=name), height = 0.05) + 
  geom_smooth(aes(value,mpg, colour=name), method="glm", method.args = list(family = "binomial")) +
  facet_wrap(~name, scales="free_x")
```

[image]